# Android: Differences between bound and started services

Tags: android, service

I am trying to identify the main conceptual (not implementation) differences between a bound and started service. Here are the main points:

1. A bound service allows extended two way communication between the activity and the service whereas a started service need not return any results to the client activity
2. A bound service will service multiple clients (as long as there is at least one client bound to it) while a started service performs a single operation and then shuts down. (I am aware that there can be started services which are also bound)

   Are there any other major differences?

Answer (score 7):

See bellow image perhaps help to you :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should have cited the source.

Comment: This source might be from Pluralsight tutorials - Services - By Sriyank Siddhartha

Comment: Do we have to call `unbind` explicitly?

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is that bound service will get terminated by Android OS when the last client has unbound, started service however does not need any clients and it can run. As you already mentioned, you can also make a service that can support multi client communication, but is not bound

Difference also arises when you try to stop them. When you call `stopService(..)` on a bound service and it still has a client bound to it, nothing will happen while on the other hand, the started service will get terminated. When you call `unbindService` on a started service nothing happens, while if your service bound and this is the last client, it will shut down.... so over all the only difference between them is how they are started and stopped eventually

Apart from that, there is no difference.

Comment: Is a bound service the preferred choice for extended two way communication?

Comment: @Amit it depends. If you want other apps to be able to communicate with your service, you **must** use AIDL to do the work. I've also seen people to prefer this way, but this makes your service public so I prefer the handler way (what you are referring to), unless I want it to be public.

Comment: Started services can get terminated by Android OS for no specified reason.