# Will Android ever arbitrarily close a bound, started service?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-mediarecorder

I have an instance of Android MediaRecorder running in a LifecycleService that has been bound to (bindService) and started (startService) by an activity.

The MediaRecorder is meant to be recording audio, even when the activity itself is in the background, due to other apps being open on the screen.

I'm aware that Android can sometimes close services under certain circumstances, such as it needing resources elsewhere.

Do I need to worry that Android could close a bound, started service like mine?

In the circumstance that concerns me, the service would still have a binding (the activity), and it would still had an active task (the recording would running), so [based on this Stackover answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30408803/android-differences-between-bound-and-started-services) it would have two reasons not to disappear. But is that enough to *guarantee* that the service will survive?

If not, are there steps I can take to ensure the service never disappears? A wakelock in the service, for instance?

And out of curiousity, would the fact that the service is running MediaRecorder make any difference? Surely Android would know not to close an active MediaRecorder session, no?

Lastly, if services are arbitrarily closed despite all efforts to prevent it, is there a better class I could be using for my MediaRecorder, one that can keep running in the background even when the Activity/Fragment is in the background?

thanks

John

Comment: I don't think there's any way you can prevent a Service from being killed.

Comment: One step you could take would be to make it a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground).  If you do so, you'll need to display a notification to the user, but this is a common paradigm for media apps.

Comment: You can create an system service

Comment: Anything can and will be killed when there is enough resource pressure.  The best that you can do is make it less likely that a component will be killed by telling the system that the component ikely has the user's attention.  In your case, I think a foreground Service is your best bet.  In the heirarchy of things that Android priorities to kill when under memory pressure, foreground services are pretty low.